# php email validation not recognizing .com.com

Tags: php, email, email-validation

Given below is the test code for the issue

If an invalid email with extension .com.com is given it is treated as valid

Please help to resolve the same

Thanks in advance

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
function validate_email($email)
  {
    $exp = "^[a-z\'0-9]+([._-][a-z\'0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([._-][a-z0-9]+))+$";
      if(eregi($exp,$email))
      {
       if(checkdnsrr(array_pop(explode("@",$email)),"MX"))
        {
          return 1;
        }
        else
        {
          return 0;
        }
    }
  else
  {
    return 0;
  }    
}

    $email = $_POST['email'];   
    print $details= validate_email($email);
}

?>
<form action="" method="post">
 <h1> Email </h1>
 <input type="email" name="email">
 <button type="submit" name="submit"> SUBMIT </button> 
</form>
```

Comment: Don't roll your own email validator. Just use `filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`.

Comment: Also `foo@bar.com.com` is technically a valid email address - someone somewhere owns com.com, and subdomains are a thing. `user@subdomain.domain.top-level-domain` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How should it know that that email address is wrong?

A valid email address is already "someone@company"

Where "company" could be your intranet systems hostname. For reasons like that FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL doesn't check for a "valid" TLD, as it could not know if it is valid.

As for that it is recommended to NOT write a more specific check on your own, as in a lot of scenarios those checks could render your application useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`$pattern = "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$/i";`

or Just

`filter_var('email@email',FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use this regex :

```
^([a-z\'0-9\._-]+)@([a-z0-9]+)((\.[a-z0-9]{2,3})(\.[a-z0-9]{2})|(\.[a-z0-9]{2,3}))$
```

Working well with "john.doe@gmail.com" or "john.doe@domain.co.uk", but it's very difficult to match all the possibilities now too many different tld are availables.

You should try the API of an email verification service.

Regards